# How to set a breakpoint while debugging a crashdump?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, visual-studio-2015, crash-dumps

I have a `crashdump` file generated on windows and I have all the necessary PDB files on the same system. When I open the `crashdump` in Visual Studio 2015 it shows the line of code where exactly the application crashed.

However, if I put a breakpoint somewhere in the same and try to start debugging the dump file, the breakpoints don't hit. Can anyone help me achieve this. I want to see the flow of execution of the application before it crashed.

Comment: Did you add the related pdb files into Symbol file location in VS(`Tools-->Options-->Debugging-->Symbol`) and then empty symbol cache?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Yes, that's how it shows the point of crash in the proper file and line number.